# て Ending, Short Phrase, and Possibly Fake Saying

Tags: て-form, idioms, anime, proverbs

In this anime clip: https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=4iN2N8KgAw4
Gabriel uses poor Japanese to convey that Japanese is difficult and mentions a saying.

As for the first sentence, what is the purpose of くて in 難しくて?
My guess was that it is present perfect tense, but I cannot recall seeing it used in that way before.

Secondly, she says "tomoimasushine".
If I could get a breakdown of what that phrase is supposed to be literally and what was actually conveyed in the sense of poor communication, that would be nice. (shine at the end being conveyed as die, for instance.)

And lastly, is "three years the car, eight years the pole" a real saying? I could not find any information on it online when searching in English.
Thanks!

Comment: It's "oar", not "car".

Comment: /facepalm I guess that makes more sense.

Comment: 'Cause one's got a weasel and the other's got a flag! One's on the oar, shove the other in a bag!

Answer (score 4):

This しね is not 死ね, but the particle し, which conveys that the clause is one reasong among several, and the end particle ね serving its usual function. とも言います is essentially just 'they [also] say'.

難しくて is the て form of 難しい. It indicates that there's more to the sentence left unsaid, like 'Japanese is difficult, [and so I messed up]'.